# Text Area linked with drop down

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a drop down linked to a text area, so that when a choice is selected from the drop down the textarea automatically populates from the same model.  A working version can be seen here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BobNoel/kTYJg/9/)

What I'm trying to do is programatically change the drop down and have that change reflected in the text area.  I can update the drop down by setting the value and while the dropdown appears correct the change is not cascaded to the text area.  ng-change doesn't fire when the dropdown is set manually, and I cannot set the value of the text area since it's a relational product of the dropdown model.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
            <div class="inputItem sectionArea">
                <label>Sample List:</label>
                <select class="allVars"
                        ng-change="selectAction()"
                        ng-model="allVarsDD"
                        ng-options="allVars.text_short for allVars in allVars"
                        >
                        <option value="">-- Select Option --</option>
                </select>
                <br/>
                <textarea class="frequentInstructions inputLine" type="textarea" name="frequentInstructions"
                          ng-model="allVarsDD.text_long"
                </textarea>
             </div>
<div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('app', []);
function Ctrl($scope) {  
$scope.allVars=[
    {"fid":"1","environment":"0","text_short":"Short text 1","text_long":"text_long_1"},
    {"fid":"1","environment":"0","text_short":"Short text 2","text_long":"text_long_2"},
    {"fid":"1","environment":"0","text_short":"Short text 3","text_long":"text_long_3"}
    ];
}
</script>
```

Comment: you haven't shared the code where you are setting `allVarsDD` programatically...

Comment: also ng-change is not fired if you change the value inside js code

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the proper syntax for setting:

In this example to set it to item #1:
$scope.allVarsDD = $scope.allVars[1];

I updated the fiddle to reflect the correct usage.